# Changing custom child property doesn't update parent class's control

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, typeconverter

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but I've created a custom control with a property that features subproperties using a type converter that inherits `ExpandableObjectConverter`.

It seems like I've got everything set up correctly, but when I try to change any of the subproperties of the parent property, the display in the designer doesn't change until I click another property (e.g. if I change the `Color1` property of an object that uses my custom `Gradient` class for its color, the color will not change in the designer until I click off of that property or object).

The code is included below.

---

The `IndicatorBar` control class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class IndicatorBar
    Private _Percentage As Double
    Private ReadOnly _BackGradient, _BarGradient As Gradient
    Private _Side As SourceSide

    ...

    <Description("Expand to set the colors of the background gradient."), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property BackGradient As Gradient
        Get
            Return _BackGradient
        End Get
    End Property

    <Description("Expand to set the colors of the bar gradient."), Category("Appearance"), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)>
    Public ReadOnly Property BarGradient As Gradient
        Get
            Return _BarGradient
        End Get
    End Property

    ...

    Private Sub IndicatorBar_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        Dim backRect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)
        Dim maskRect As RectangleF
        Dim bar As New Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height)

        Select Case Side
            Case SourceSide.Left
                maskRect = New RectangleF(0, 0, Width * Percentage, Height)
            Case SourceSide.Top
                maskRect = New RectangleF(0, 0, Width, Height * Percentage)
            Case SourceSide.Right
                maskRect = New RectangleF(Width * (1.0 - Percentage), 0, Width * Percentage, Height)
            Case SourceSide.Bottom
                maskRect = New RectangleF(0, Height * (1.0 - Percentage), Width, Height * Percentage)
        End Select
        Using backGrad As New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(backRect, BackGradient.Color1, BackGradient.Color2, BackGradient.Angle)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backGrad, backRect)
        End Using
        e.Graphics.SetClip(maskRect)
        Using barGrad As New Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(bar, BarGradient.Color1, BarGradient.Color2, BarGradient.Angle)
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(barGrad, bar)
        End Using
        e.Graphics.ResetClip()
    End Sub
End Class
```

---

The `Gradient` class:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

<TypeConverter(GetType(GradientConverter))>
Public Class Gradient

    Private _Angle As UShort = 0
    Private _Color1, _Color2 As Color

    Public Sub New()
        Color1 = SystemColors.ControlLight
        Color2 = SystemColors.ControlLightLight
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal c1 As Color, ByVal c2 As Color)
        Color1 = c1
        Color2 = c2
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal c1 As Color, ByVal c2 As Color, ByVal ang As UShort)
        Color1 = c1
        Color2 = c2
        Angle = ang
    End Sub

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Property Color1 As Color
        Get
            Return _Color1
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _Color1 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.Repaint), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)>
    Public Property Color2 As Color
        Get
            Return _Color2
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            _Color2 = value
        End Set
    End Property

    <Browsable(True), NotifyParentProperty(True), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always), DefaultValue(0)>
    Public Property Angle As UShort
        Get
            Return _Angle
        End Get
        Set(value As UShort)
            _Angle = value Mod 360
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

---

The `GradientConverter` class:

```
Public Class GradientConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, culture As Globalization.CultureInfo, value As Object, destinationType As Type) As Object
        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            Return ""
        End If
        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: There is no way to know why your code doest work without seeing the code that doesnt work.  Few here have working crystal balls.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I've added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, turn on `Option Strict` there are 8 or so implicit conversions in your code.  I'd also change the `Angle` type.  `LinearGradientBrush` expects a single, but you have it as `UShort`.

#### Part 1

Since the `Gradient` property is *itself* a Type (class), you need to notify the parent when a child element changes.  In other words in `IndicartorBar.BarGradient.ColorX` - you want a notification to bubble up *2 levels* to `IndicatorBar` who performs the painting.

I suspect that it what you were trying to do with `NotifyParentProperty` and `RefreshProperties`.  The problem is that a change to `Color1` will only notify `Gradient`.  Additionally, attributes don't automatically interact with the Class or Property they decorate.  Most often, they are instruction to something else like a Designer or Serializer.

The solution is to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` which is simple and doesn't change the code much:

```
Public Class Gradient
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    ...
    ' VS will add this when you press ENTER on the Implements line
    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object,
         e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    ...

    Public Property Color2 As Color
        Get
            Return _Color2
        End Get
        Set(value As Color)
            If value <> _Color2 Then
                _Color2 = value

                RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, 
                   New PropertyChangedEventArgs("Gradient"))
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
```

Modify both `Color1` and `Color2` setters to fire the event.  Then on `IndicatorBar` we need to subscribe to the event and respond:

```
Public Class IndicatorBar
    ...
    ' I have no idea why these were ReadOnly
    Private WithEvents _BackGradient, _BarGradient As Gradient
    ...

    Private Sub _BackGradient_PropertyChanged(sender As Object,
        e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Handles BackGradient.PropertyChanged, 
               _BarGradient.PropertyChanged

        Me.Invalidate()

    End Sub
```

Now, when either `Color#` changes on either `Gradient` as soon as the color picker dropdown closes, the `UserControl` will be notified and the control should be redrawn immediately as a result of `Invalidate()`.

To add it for `Angle` just raise the event in that setter as above.  Also be sure to Clean and Rebuild the project before testing the changes.

#### Part 2

Another problem is that your `TypeConverter` isn't doing anything.  It inherits from `ExpandableObjectConverter`, so the child properties collapse.  But when collapsed, the TypeConverter is supposed to provide a summary as with `Font` or `Location`.

Your `ConvertTo` is supposed to provide that summary if the child properties.

```
Public Class GradientConverter
    Inherits ExpandableObjectConverter

    ' when the designer asks if we can convert to string,
    ' reply "Yes, I can!"
    Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext, 
                           destinationType As Type) As Boolean

        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return MyBase.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(context As ITypeDescriptorContext,
                                        culture As Globalization.CultureInfo,
                                        value As Object,
                                        destinationType As Type) As Object
        If destinationType Is GetType(String) Then
            ' cast value to our Type
            Dim grad As Gradient = CType(value, Gradient)

            ' return the prop summary
            Return String.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", grad.Angle.ToString,
                                    grad.Color1.ToString,
                                    grad.Color2.ToString)
        End If
        Return MyBase.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType)
    End Function
End Class
```

Now, your 2 `Gradient` properties will summarize the 3 child props, and update as you change them:

[image]

Note:
If you wanted to allow the string form of the 3 child properties to be edited by the user (e.g. let them type "Blue" over one of the colors *without* expanding or opening the `Gradient` property, you'd have to implement `CanConvertFrom` / `ConvertFrom` to convert the text to valid property values.

In such cases, be careful how you decorate or separate the individual values (e.g. the uses 2 commas in the text).  Your `ConvertFrom` code will have to parse the formatted string to pull out those values (also keep in mind the user may have removed or changed the delimiters).

Comment: I've made the suggested changes. The parent property is now showing the summary of its child properties. However, the primary problem of the changes not immediately showing up on the control itself is still there. Only after changing a property that calls `Me.Invalidate()` or deselecting the control do the changes to the child property show up on the control.

Comment: Ooh...so there's nothing I can do to change that behavior with a `UserControl`? What about using custom events and event handlers?

Comment: Ah-HAH! I had experimented with INotifyPropertyChanged before, but couldn't get it to do anything...now I know it's because I was missing one of the most important steps: getting the grandparent class to subscribe to the events! Thanks a bunch, that solved the problem!

Comment: Don't worry about the earlier confusion. I didn't realize until after the first version of your answer that I hadn't worded the question very clearly.

Comment: The confusion was partly mine - the TypeConverter was so obviously doing nothing, I transposed "update control" to "update property display".